# Hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Does there exist a compact hyperbolic manifold (i.e.,all sectional curvatures are -1) with the same volume as the round-sphere of the same dimension? Does such a manifold exist for any dimension greater than four?

Comment: Do you mean the unit sphere, the sphere of constant curvature 1?